# CSS inheritance issue. Help on css please.

Tags: jquery, css, inheritance

I'm trying to add a flyout to an existing accordion menu that was from http://vtimbuc.net/. The code is on JSFidle, can someone kindly show me how to have border below the a tag ( Sign OUt > Freeze Account > Sub 1 ) and also different background on hover for the flyout menu ( My Files > Skydrive > Sub Product 1 .... )

I'm still a newbie in CSS and I've tried a few things and didn't had any luck and I think it's because of the CSS inheritance which I'm not familiar

http://jsfiddle.net/QhAu5/14/

Thanks !

Comment: You may be a newbie but you added a fiddle! +1 for you!

Comment: please add the relevant code to your question, for future reference should jsfiddle.com ever go down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the colors to whatever you want.

For border bottom

```
ul.sub-menu li.sub_nav2 ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

For background color

```
ul.sub-menu li.sub_nav2 ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QhAu5/16/

Answer (score 0):

To add a border below the 'a' tag:

```
.sub_nav2 li {
    border-bottom:1px 'solid your color here';
}
```

To change flyout background color:

```
.sub_nav2 li a:hover {
    background: 'your color here';
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. JSFiddle been updated. Last few lines of codes at the bottom of the css frame , it seems like the .sub_nav li is inheriting the parent li